# The best way to call a js from cakephp action

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp

Suppose that a have one action to add an user very simple:

```
$this->Model->save($this->request->data);
```

And, after save the user, I want to make a notification with the [Noty.js](http://needim.github.io/noty/)

What's the best way to call this JS? 
And, if I want to call a different noty in various actions, I have to create many JS scripts with different messages?
How I can create an function to call noty more simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple, conditionally run the Noty.js code in your view based on whether `$this->Model->save()` was successful.

Controller:

```
$success = $this->Model->save($this->request->data);
$this->set('success', $success);
```

View:

```
<?php if ($success): ?>
    <script>
        // Trigger your Noty.js dialog here.
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```